# How to update two keys in a dictionary with info from one Popup window in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to update dictionary `collected_info` key `'Liners'` keys `'4x20'` and `'8x20'` with info from a `ColorsPopup` popup, but I'm having issues doing it correctly.

The idea is, that when either of the two buttons is pressed, a popup appears, that contains multiple coloured buttons inside. After you toggle buttons inside the popup, it should add those colours as a list to the corresponding key (either `'4x20'` or `'8x20'`).

The problem is, I cannot implement all the required functionality.

My current issue is that I can't separate list of `liners` for each of the `collected_info` keys - 4x20 and 8x10.

Here's MRE python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton


class ProtocolInfoPage(Screen):
    big = ObjectProperty(None)
    small = ObjectProperty(None)
    collected_info = {'Liners': {'4x20': list(), '8x10': list()}}

    def open_popup(self, liner):
        popup = ColorsPopup()
        if liner == '4x20' and self.big.state == 'down':
            popup.popupWindow.open()
            self.collected_info['Liners']['4x20'] = popup.liners
        elif liner == '4x20' and self.big.state == 'normal':
            self.collected_info['Liners']['4x20'] = []
        if liner == '8x10' and self.small.state == 'down':
            popup.popupWindow.open()
            self.collected_info['Liners']['8x10'] = popup.liners
        elif liner == '8x10' and self.small.state == 'normal':
            self.collected_info['Liners']['8x10'] = []


class ColorsPopup(Screen):
    liners = list()
    colors = ['GB', 'BL', 'GR', 'RT', 'SW', 'BR', 'TR']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ColorsPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        layout = GridLayout(cols=3, size_hint=(.7, .7), pos_hint={'center_x': .5})
        self.popupWindow = Popup(title='Flatliner Colors', content=main_layout, size_hint=(1, .5), auto_dismiss=False)
        close_btn = Button(text='Choose Colors', size_hint=(.7, .3), pos_hint={'center_x': .5})
        close_btn.bind(on_press=self.popupWindow.dismiss)
        for color in self.colors:
            color_btn = ToggleButton(text=color)
            color_btn.bind(state=self.adding_removing_colors)
            if color == 'GB':
                color_btn.background_color = (1, 1, 0, 1)
            elif color == 'BL':
                color_btn.background_color = (0, 0, 1, 1)
            elif color == 'GR':
                color_btn.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
            elif color == 'RT':
                color_btn.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
            elif color == 'SW':
                color_btn.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
            elif color == 'BR':
                color_btn.background_color = (.5, .5, .3, 1)
            layout.add_widget(color_btn)
        main_layout.add_widget(layout)
        main_layout.add_widget(close_btn)

    def adding_removing_colors(self, color, state):
        if state == 'down':
            self.liners.append(color.text)
        elif state == 'normal':
            self.liners.remove(color.text)
        print(self.liners)


kv = Builder.load_file("kivymd.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

print(ProtocolInfoPage.collected_info)
```

And here's kv:

```
ProtocolInfoPage:
    name: 'second'
    big: big_liners
    small: small_liners

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: 'Liners'
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                ToggleButton:
                    id: big_liners
                    text: '4x20'
                    on_release:
                        root.open_popup(self.text)
                ToggleButton:
                    id: small_liners
                    text: '8x10'
                    on_release:
                        root.open_popup(self.text)
```

I have reworked how `ColorsPopup` work, and I feel like this implementation is better than just writing it in kv file, but I still cant figure out a way to do it correctly.

Comment: Here, every time the popup opens the toggle buttons will be in normal state. So how would you clarify the following: *'but even if they decided afterwards to change colours...'* ?

Comment: Well, the toggle button should change it state to downed when pressed, and then the user can unpress it back to normal state, which will trigger the popup again allowing them to add or remove the colors.
As I see, currently after pressing main buttons they stay pressed, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Let's make it clear, the toggle buttons you added in popup as colour options will be in normal state every time you open it. So how would the users identify later which colour they've already chosen ? I assume you also need to implement this or set another strategy.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. I thought about buttons in the popup being regular ones, and changing their background color slightly to indicate that particular color is added, but it never really worked as intended.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a bother, but I have abandoned the idea that colors buttons stay pressed, now it works like this - first press of a main button toggles it, and popup appears, then you can choose colors to be added, and close the popup. After you close it, if you toggle the button again, it will change the status back to 'normal' and erase everything from that list.

All I need now, is for info to be assigned to the correct key. I've tried instantiating ColorsPopup depending on what main button is pressed, but that did not help, and values from both popups end up in one list.

Comment: If you could take a look and maybe direct me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your logic is you are modifying `collected_info` with the value of `popup.liners` during instantiation of popup which is empty by default. Hence you never can access it when it changes inside the popup. This can be solved in various ways.

One simple way is to observe the changes of `popup.liners` and update your `collected_info` accordingly. Now that's exactly what `bind` does. For that, create a suitable (kivy) property and bind a callback method/function whenever or wherever you need.

The following is the implementation of this concept. I have added an extra `Label` to reflect the changes in real time. Rest have been clarified in comments.

Modified `.kv`,

```py
ProtocolInfoPage:
    name: 'second'
#    big: big_liners
#    small: small_liners

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label: # To visualize the change. Optional.
            id: info
            size_hint_y: 0.25
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: 'Liners'
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                ToggleButton:
#                    id: big_liners
                    text: '4x20'
                    on_state: root.select_option(self) # Pass the instance.
#                    on_release:
#                        root.open_popup(self.text)
                ToggleButton:
#                    id: small_liners
                    text: '8x10'
                    on_state: root.select_option(self)
#                    on_release:
#                        root.open_popup(self.text)
```

Modified `.py`,

```py
class ProtocolInfoPage(Screen):
    big = ObjectProperty(None)
    small = ObjectProperty(None)
    collected_info = {'Liners': {'4x20': list(), '8x10': list()}}

    def select_option(self, tbtn):
        # Create an instance and save it to self.
        self.popup = ColorsPopup()
        # Now bind a callback function to it in order to listen to any change in its prop. 'liners'.
        # Pass the toggle button also for usage purpose.
        self.popup.bind(liners = lambda *args : self.update_collected_info(tbtn, *args))
        # Using partial.
#       self.popup.bind(liners = partial(self.update_collected_info, tbtn))
        # Set logic.
        if tbtn.state == "normal":
            self.collected_info['Liners'][tbtn.text] = []
        else: # i.e. when tbtn.state is "down", open the popup.
            self.popup.popupWindow.open()
        # Update the info. Optional.
        self.ids.info.text = str(self.collected_info)


    def update_collected_info(self, tbtn, instance, value):
        """This method will be triggered whenever the prop. 'liners' of ColorsPopup changes."""
        self.collected_info['Liners'][tbtn.text] = value
        # Update the info. Optional.
        self.ids.info.text = str(self.collected_info)


class ColorsPopup(Screen):
    liners = ListProperty([ ]) # Make it a kivy property in order to listen to its changes automatically.
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, for detailed explanation and example. I'm still struggling with the whole bind a callback to a property change, but with your continues help I'm definitely on the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again after a month, (I dont know if you are even notified but still), but I've stumbled upon some issues while trying to compile my project, because of the functools module.

Is there a way to rewrite line with the partial method using lamda function? I'm having troubles comprehending how to do it, so I was wondering if you had an idea. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem while compiling with the function `partial` as this is included in the python distribution. However you can also use anonymous `lambda`, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I forgot to reply, sorry. You were absolutely correct, and helped me again! :)